# Should we split the tools tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Currently the [tools](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) tag is covering just about every kind tool, equipment or device in use in the garden.

Do we carry on this way? Or should we think about splitting them out. I'm thinking lawnmower is important enough to get its own tag and I'm wondering whether hand tools vs. engine/mechanical equipment should also be split.

Possibilities:

[lawnmower](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lawnmower) (or [lawn-mower](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lawn-mower)?)
[hand-tools](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hand-tools)
[equipment](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given there's only 11 tools questions, I'd do little until there's a larger sample.  The one thing that sticks out as useful now is [lawn-mower].

Comment: lawn-mower tag done

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. I can't think of really meaningful subcategories you'd want to search on. For instance, if I want to know about keeping blades sharp enough to cut plant X I'll search on tools, but if I'm asking specifically about cutting lawn, then a simple string search would do the trick.